# In iOS 11 didEnterRegion & didExitRegion not working when authorizedWhenInUse is granted otherwise its working fine

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, core-location, geofencing

I download the project from here

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

and did little modification according to requirement

1. xcode said description missing so I add these in info.plist

   Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description

   Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
2. In `GeotificationsViewController` I modified this

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
           mapView.showsUserLocation = status == .authorizedAlways|| status == .authorizedWhenInUse 
        }

When I grant `authorizedAlways` every thing works fine but when `authorizedWhenInUse` is granted its not delivering the `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion`

App is open, running, active, visible on screen in both scenarios.

xcode Version 9.2, 
iOS 11.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For region based monitoring operation you must be to gather `authorizedAlways` permission from user.

For more reference check this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization

> Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such
>   as region monitoring or the significant location change service.

Comment: But what if user only want to use this feature when app is running, user dont want to grant authorizedAlways

Comment: Then region monitoring won't work; it is their choice; If they only grant "when in use" then they won't get region monitoring functionality.  You could detect this permission setting and display an alert explaining that the user needs to grant "always" permission from settings if they want full functionality from your app

Comment: But dont you think that "when in use" is kind of confusing for user, He/She will think it will provide full functionality while app is running.